# How to include folders in Powershell -include string

Tags: powershell

I am doing some batch file name updates and am having trouble including folders. I have it currently set to target only specific file types, but I also want to include folders. Since folders don't have an extension I am unsure how to specify folders in the "-include" string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I am currently working with, but it ignores folders when I would like them included.

```
Get-ChildItem k:/toolbox/powershell -Include *.gif, *.jpg, *.png, *.xls, 
*.xlsx, *.ppt, *.pptx, *.doc, *.docx, *.pdf -recurse | where {$_.name -match 
"_"} | foreach {
  $New=$_.name.Replace("_","-")
  Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
}
```

Comment: the `-Include` parameter - for whatever reason - does not act on dir names ... it only acts on the `.Name` part of a _file name_. [*sigh ...*] i've been told that it works on ps7, but have not tested that. ///// that means you will need to do any dir name filtering after you get your items from the `G-CI` call.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` does have a switchparameter `-Directory` since at least version 4.0 that will return directories only. You may need to do this as two statements - one as your current version, and one where instead of the `-Include` you use `-Directory`.

Comment: In order to include directories, you have to say *. Believe it or not. *.* won't match.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-Item '~\Desktop\*') | foreach { $FolderName = $_.name.Replace("_","-"); Rename-Item -path $_.fullname -newname $FolderName -passthru }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add 2nd statement:

```
Get-ChildItem "k:/toolbox/powershell" -Recurse |where mode -eq d----- | where {$_.name -match "_"} | foreach {$New=$_.name.Replace("_","-")
Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru }
```

If you run `Get-ChildItem "k:/toolbox/powershell"` you will receive a list of items where the "Mode" is "d-----" for directories, hence you can use that filter criteria for directories